# Using beanshell variable in subsequent While loop

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I need to use variable from beanshell in my while loop, but I am not able to see the value of variable coming through.

output variable of my JDBC select count(*) query is "count_num"

using following code in beanshell:

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("count_num_1").trim());
```

Following is the structure of my test plan:

```
-JDBC request (o/p variable is count_num)
-beanshell sampler (parse string count_num to integer)
-While Controller: vars.get(${i})>0)   
  -http request1
  -http request2
  - (beanshell code to decrease "i" by 5 - not sure how??)
```

What am i doing wrong in usage of "i" and also how to decrease count of "i" by 5 towards the end of while loop.

Comment: I updated my typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put variable string value after adding 5

```
 vars.put("count_num_1", String.valueOf(id +5));
```

Comment: I tried using  following code:
    try {
        int id = vars.get("count_dcn_1");
       id = id - 5;
       vars.put ("count_dcn_1",String.valueOf(id));
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        log.error("Error in Beanshell", ex);
        throw ex;
    }


Error: Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `` try { int id = vars.get("count_dcn_1"); id = id - 5; vars.put ("count_dcn_1",St . . . '' : TargetError

Comment: I am sorry about the formatting, somehow I am having trouble formatting comment section using mac, specially for code.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Could you also help me understanding why my while loop won't work.
my while loop has code::: ${count_num_1}>0

the above code which we used for decrementing the value of count_num_1 is working, but then code within while loop still keep getting executed.

Comment: Actually, following code worked:

${__javaScript(parseInt(${count_dcn_1})>0)}